# Retrieving Gmail emails using C# and Gmail API: Getting data from the wrong Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api

I'm facing an issue with a C# method I've written to retrieve Gmail emails using the Gmail API. Even though I'm signed in with a specific Gmail account for authentication, let's call it GmailAccount1, I'm unexpectedly getting data from a different Gmail account, let's call it GmailAccount2.

To clarify:

I own both GmailAccount1 and GmailAccount2.
I run my application and authenticate using GmailAccount1.
However, the data I receive from the Gmail API includes emails from GmailAccount2, which is not the expected behavior.
The code I'm using looks something like this:

```
 public async Task<EmailContent> GetLastEmailOfLabelAsync()
    {
        var service = await InitializeGmailServiceAsync();
        var request = service.Users.Messages.List("me");
        request.LabelIds = "SENT";
        request.MaxResults = 1; // Get only one email (the last one)
        var messages = await request.ExecuteAsync();

        if (messages.Messages != null && messages.Messages.Count > 0)
        {
            var lastMessageId = messages.Messages.First().Id;
            var messageRequest = service.Users.Messages.Get("me", lastMessageId);
            var message = await messageRequest.ExecuteAsync();

            var emailDto = new EmailContent();

            // Parse email headers to get sender and subject
            foreach (var header in message.Payload.Headers)
            {
                if (header.Name == "From")
                {
                    emailDto.From = header.Value;
                }
                else if (header.Name == "Subject")
                {
                    emailDto.Subject = header.Value;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        return null; // No messages found for the label
    }I suspect that the issue may be related to the way I'm authenticating with Gmail APIs, but I'm unsure how to resolve it. Can someone please help me understand what's causing this issue and how to ensure that I only get data from GmailAccount1 when using the Gmail API?
```

Thank you!